# Login form validation with jQuery issue

Tags: php, jquery, html

im trying to validate a form with jQuery and php, I've followed a few tutorials but none of them worked for me. I really have no idea what's going on, I've tried in several different ways, so I hope someone knows what's the issue, why it happens and how to solve it.

So... here is my login.php

```
<?php
    $meta_description = "Ingrese a su cuenta para poder realizar diferentes operaciones";
    $page_title = "Login - Estudio Benintendi";
    include("includes/header.php")
?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Ingrese los siguientes datos para logearse</legend>
            <div id="resultado"></div>
            <label>Nombre de usuario</label>
            <div class="input-control text" data-role="input-control">
                <input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Ingrese su nombre de usuario..." required />
                <button class="btn-clear" tabindex="-1" type="button"></button>
            </div>
            <label>Contraseña</label>
            <div class="input-control password" data-role="input-control">
                <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Ingrese su contraseña..." autofocus required />
                <button class="btn-reveal" tabindex="-1" type="button"></button>
                </div>
            <div class="input-control checkbox" data-role="input-control">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" checked>
                <span class="check"></span>
                Recordarme
                </label>
            </div>
            <p><button id="submit">Enviar</button></p>
        </fieldset>
    </form>

<?php include("includes/footer.php") ?>
```

Here is my login.js

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    $("#submit").on("click", function(){
        username = $("#username").val();
        password = $("#password").val();
        $.ajax({
                url: "/includes/validar_login.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {username:username, password:password},
                done: function(resp){
                    if(resp == "true")
                    {
                        window.location = "index.php";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $("#resultado").html(resp);
                    }
                }   
            });
    });
});
```

Here is my php script that actually connects to the db

```
<?php
    require_once("config.php");

    session_start();

    $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE) or die ("No se pudo conectar a la base de datos");

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $sql = "SELECT Nombre FROM usuarios WHERE Nombre='$username' AND Password='$password'";

    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows == 1)
    {
        $_SESSION["username"] = $username;
        echo "true";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "false";
    }

    $conn->close();
?>
```

And finally here is my footer.php (which I use in all the pages)

```
 </div>
        <!-- jQuery 2.1.1 -->
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <!-- jQuery UI -->
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery.widget.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Cross-Browser plugin-->
        <script src="js/jquery/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Metro jQuery customs -->
        <script src="js/metro/metro.min.js"></script>

        <script src="js/login.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Obviously I want to remove login.js from the footer, because I don't want him to display in all the pages, but I can't make this work yet, so I display it in all the pages.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add: I've tried with ajax "success" and didn't work either !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set cache to false and datatype to json.

```
$("#submit").on("click", function(){
    var obj = {'username':$("#username").val(),'password':$("#password").val()};
    Post(obj);
});

function Post(arr) {
    console.log(arr);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/includes/validar_login.php",
        data: arr,
        cache: false,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
}
```

And for your php:

```
<?php

    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];

    $response = array('username'=>$username,'password'=>$password);
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Then take a look in console, if you get any response

Comment: I also have some rewrite rules in .htaccess, may this cause a problem?

Comment: That I dont know. But I guess not.

Comment: @N3HL this simple setup should work for a test. I just worked with this today.

Comment: Well the only thing I get is "uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token function"

Comment: Clean Console, you can take a look at the "live demo" at http://estudiobenintendi.com.ar/login

Comment: I just saw it. But i think you refresh the page, so the console cleans :)

Comment: Why would that happen? I mean I deleted action="" recently, so why does the page refresh?

Comment: Yes I recently took 2 chrome pages and saw this

Object {username: "example", password: "12345"}

Then the page refreshed !

Comment: So ajax works now. Then you can work with the data i suppose.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just needed to handle submit event on form, returning false like this

$('#formlogin').submit(function () {
    var obj = {'username':$("#username").val(),'password':$("#password").val()};
    Post(obj);
 return false;
});

I tried this and the page didn't refresh and the data remained in console, I think I can finish this now.

Answer (score 0):

Try This for your js:

```
$(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        queryString = $(this).parents('form:first').serialize(); //serialize all valid form inputs/controls
        $.post('/includes/validar_login.php',queryString, function(data){
                    var resp = JSON.parse(data);
            if(resp == "true")
            {
                window.location = "index.php";
            }else{
                $("#resultado").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```

in your `validar_login.php`

change echo 'true' and echo 'false' to die(json_encode('true')) and die(json_encode('false'))